# Recuperar dados em PHP dentro de um texto

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte texto:

```
$texto = "Olá {cliente}, seja bem vindo ao site {site}!
Aqui você terá acesso as seguintes opções:
{opcoes}

Estes dados foram gerados automaticamente em {data}
Pela empresa {empresa}";
```

Note que temos várias `tags` entre os chaves, preciso elaborar um `PHP` que recupera apenas estas tags, e as coloque dentro de um `array()`, pois farei a inclusão das tags numa tabela diferenciada.

Como eu poderia recuperar apenas os que estiverem dentro das chaves?

O resultado que eu gostaria seria:

```
Array (
      [0] => {x},
      [1] => {y}
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
$texto = "Olá {cliente}, seja bem vindo ao site {site}!
Aqui você terá acesso as seguintes opções:
{opcoes}

Estes dados foram gerados automaticamente em {data}
Pela empresa {empresa}";

preg_match_all('/\{(.*?)\}/', $texto, $match);
print_r($match[0]); // Array ( [0] => {cliente} [1] => {site} [2] => {opcoes} [3] => {data} [4] => {empresa} )
```

Também funciona assim:

```
preg_match_all('#\{(.*?)\}#', $texto, $match);
```

Note que assim cada valor do `$match[0]` tem as "{...}" incluidas, se não as quiser pode aceder ao indice 1:

```
print_r($match[1]); // Array ( [0] => cliente [1] => site [2] => opcoes [3] => data [4] => empresa )
```

Comment: Você foi mais rápido :P

Comment: Bem isso, perfeita resposta.

Comment: :) hehe Ussain bolt do preg_match @Inkeliz :P

Comment: @AndréBaill adicionei outra opção com uma expressão regular alternativa

Comment: Certo Miguel, me diga uma coisa... Eu consigo recuperar estes dados por um jquery? Exemplo, tenho um campo chamado descricao, input normal, conforme eu for digitando os textos, ele vai listando estas tags embaixo?

Comment: Desta maneira você manda o texto todo para o servidor e está a processa-lo com php, mas poderia mandar para o servidor só as tags, ou seja, fazer este processo em javascript e mandar somente as tags

Comment: Na verdade, eu queria exibir, na tela, quais são as tags do texto que está sendo elaborado, ou que ele vai colar dentro do campo... pra que ele saiba as tags que vai usar.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44533/discussion-between-miguel-and-andre-baill).

Answer (score 1):

O [Miguel respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/149257/6454) muito bem a pergunta, segue apenas outra alternativa usando as funções [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php) e [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php):

```
function recuperarTags($texto){
    $inicio = 0;
    $tags = [];

    while (($inicio = strpos($texto, "{", $inicio)) !== false) {
        $final = strpos($texto, '}', $inicio + 1);
        $tamanho = $final - $inicio;
        $tag = substr($texto, $inicio + 1, $tamanho - 1);

        $tags[] = $tag;
        $inicio += 1;
    }
    return $tags;
}
```

Para usar, faça assim:

```
$texto = "Olá {cliente}, seja bem vindo ao site {site}!
Aqui você terá acesso as seguintes opções:
{opcoes}

Estes dados foram gerados automaticamente em {data}
Pela empresa {empresa}";

$tags = recuperarTags($texto);

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo $tag ."\n";
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/fBBEpA)</kbd>